# Windows Azure. Worker role billing

Tags: azure, billing

Can somebody tell please what is the billing policy for worker role instance?

Here [Cloud Services Pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/) at the bottom a FAQ section tells

- *If my deployed instance is in the "stopped" state, do I still get billed?*

**Yes, a stopped instance still occupies the compute resource that powers the instance, and therefore you still get billed**. In order to stop billing, you need to delete your deployment.

- *If my web or worker role was deployed for less than an hour, how much do I get billed for?*

Cloud services are billed based on the duration of time your service was deployed for. If your instance was deployed for less than an hour or, multiple hours plus some fraction of hour, you will be charged for that duration only. Azure does not round up the partial hour to full hour for billing - **you pay for exactly the duration of time that your Cloud Services instance was in 'running' state**.

So what is the exact billing policy? Whether a deployed but "stopped" state worker role is get billed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're still getting billed.

The analogy here is a like a hotel room. If you still occupy a room (deployed) but you're not there (stopped) you still occupy the room and consume resources (the room cannot be reused).

Comment: Thanks! I thought so, but I was confused by the phrase "you pay for exactly the duration of time that your Cloud Services instance was in **'running' state**"